# linux user permissions with groups on file

Tags: linux, permissions, user-groups

I have one file owned by user: "ruler"

and another user: "tzook"

now I have one file that is owned by "ruler" and by group "deployers"

here is the file:

```
-rwxrwxr-- 1 ruler deployers 3040 Oct 28 12:53 fabfile.py
```

now when I am the user ruler there is no problem editing, viewing etc

but when I am user "tzook"
that the output of -->

```
$ tzook sudo www-data ruler deployers
```

is

```
tzook sudo www-data ruler deployers
```

so you can see the user tzook is in the group "deployers"
so why cant I edit or view the file?

I get "permission denied" when I use:

```
 $ ls -la fabfile.py
```

Comment: `ls` requires execute permissions on the directory containing `fabfile.py` - what are they set to?  `ls -lad ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have execute permissions in the directory.

Check your permissions by:

```
ls -ld .
```

If the directory is not owned by group 'deployers', chgrp it:

```
chgrp deployers .
```

Then give the group permissions read/execute permissions:

```
chmod g+rx .
```

Comment: yes the files had permissions, but the parent folder didn't, thanks!

Comment: you're welcome! can you upvote my answer? :)